# Calculate regression between 2 columns, then move to the next columns, then the next two, etc

Tags: python-3.x

I am utilizing the slope from the regression to calibrate my Y's to my X's. The point of the script is to blind test the calibration to determine accuracy. I am calculating a regression line between two columns in Excel, with 64 total points/samples. I have set it up where one of the 64 points will be dropped from the regression, so a slope will be calcuated from the 63 samples and that slope will be used to calibrate the Y value. I can then compare that calibrated Y to the true "X" value. I have set up a "fir i in rage(len(y))" command that basically drops one of the 64 points, run the regression, calculate accuracy, then the script drops another one of the 64 points, and this continues until each individual points have been drops and check for accuracy.

The Problem: I want to continue the loop that I talked about above, but I want to incorporate an additional loop that does all of the calculations I mentioned above, and then moves over to the next column, and repeats the action.

For example, lets say I am calculating the regression between column A1 and F1 (as stated above). After that is finished, I want it to omve one column to the right and calculations another regression, say for columns B1 and G1. Then for C1 and H1, etc.

---

```
#this was my attempt

#Columnx = Excel_XRF.iloc[: , 1]
#Columny = Excel_XRF.iloc[: , 17]
#mask = ~np.isnan(Columnx) & ~np.isnan(Columny)
#Columnx_clean = Columnx[mask]
```

### #Columny_clean = Columny[mask]

```
varx = Excel_XRF["Tix"]
vary = Excel_XRF["Tiy"]

Excel_Index = 1
Excel_Index2 = 1

mask = ~np.isnan(varx) & ~np.isnan(vary)

varx_clean = varx[mask]
vary_clean = vary[mask]


#initiate array to be filled for coefficients, r^2, and percentError
coef = []
r2 = []
PercDiff = []

for i in range(len(vary_clean)):
    yTest = vary_clean[i] #tested okay value from data
    xTrue = varx_clean[i] #tested "True" value from data

    #Remove single point iteratively from data set
    test1 = np.append(varx_clean[:i], varx_clean[i+1:])
    test2 = np.append(vary_clean[:i], vary_clean[i+1:])

    #Put shortened data into linear regression model (fit intercept to 0)
    model =LinearRegression(fit_intercept=False).fit(test1.reshape(-1,1), test2)
    coef.append(model.coef_)
    r2.append(model.score(test1.reshape(-1,1), test2))
    xTest = yTest/model.coef_
    PercDiff.append(((abs(xTest - xTrue)/(xTrue))*100)[0])

#Unnest
coefficients = list(chain.from_iterable(coef))
```